# ListBox with nothing selected shows highlighted entry

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

My ListBox is set to SelectionMode=MultiSimple.
It starts life with nothing selected, and nothing highlighted.
If I then select an entry (other than the top-most one),
it selects the item, and highlights it.
If I then select the same entry again, it de-selects it,
and the SelectedXxxx values all indicate that nothing is selected,
but the topmost line is now highlighted in error.
What is going wrong, and how do I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: is it windows or web application ? Is there any event added to listbox?

Answer (score 0):

The first item in a list box or dropdown combo box is ID 0. You should set the list box selection index to -1 to make sure nothing is selected or highlighted. Setting it to 0 sets the list box (or comb box) to select the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution.
I test to see that the selected index is -1,
and when it is I set it to 0 then back to -1 again.
This clears the unwanted highlight on row 0.